# Non default port for Bitbucket Branch Source plugin webhooks

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I use bitbucket cloud and there is no config option to change the port in `Jenkins > Configure System > Bitbucket Endpoints: Bitbucket Cloud`

It automatically creates webhooks in the repo that look like this:

```
https://myserver.mydom.com/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify
```

I need it to create webhooks that look like this:

```
https://myserver.mydom.com:9999/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the URL of the webhook is based on the value set in the "Jenkins URL" configuration option.  In Jenkins > Configure System > Jenkins Location > Jenkins URL, changes the URL to `https://myserver.mydom.com:9999`.

Comment: hmm but i have different URLs for external/internal access. My url config there just uses the default port, but for external access users hit a different endpoint with a specific port and thats routed to the server. Bitbucket Cloud is an external service so i need to use that port